# Decrypt 3DES DUKPT per the ANSI X9.24 part 1 standard

Tags: encryption, cryptography, credit-card, 3des, dukpt

I have a Magtek uDynamo and am trying to decrypt track 1. I have read the below and understand a little bit but don't know how to actually decrypt the data. The vendor said to use the ANSI test key to decrypt but I can't find anything on that. I have the KSN, session, and serial numbers. I have also tried some Java code I found, but it doesn't seem to work. It returns null or possibly I'm putting in the wrong BDK. I'm just using the serial number for that which I read somewhere. I'm doing this on Android. Preferably I would like code that runs on  the server not on the device so it goes encrypted across the line along with HTTPS.

[How ciphertext was generated in card reader using DUKPT encryption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17362567/how-ciphertext-was-generated-in-card-reader-using-dukpt-encryption)

[3DES-DUKPT (CBC) decryption confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31924957/3des-dukpt-cbc-decryption-confirmation)

https://github.com/yinheli/dukpt/blob/master/src/main/java/com/yinheli/tool/DukptDecrypt.java

**Update**
I'm looking to decrypt 3DES DUKPT per the ANSI X9.24 part 1 standard

I'm using this https://github.com/camcima/dukpt-php/tree/e8fceb4df8757e7e097c435221b4e93e097d3c9f

I had to update the files and make sure I got the most recent phpseclib and it runs but the data comes out like C��� ������4A�fr���( Wb������f�7z�n:�w�9��,��f7�,m=�z�CRW�

I must be missing something. I've tried different modes and I'm trying to look for encoding. Please let me know if you have a solution or ideas. Also their test data does work so I'm not sure what the difference is between mine and theirs

Code I'm running index.php in the root:

```
include 'vendor/autoload.php';

use DUKPT\DerivedKey;
use DUKPT\KeySerialNumber;
use DUKPT\Utility;

$encryptedHexData = 'de8bfe769dca885cf3cc312135fe2cccfacf176235f4bdee773d1865334315ed2aefcab613f1884b5d63051703d5a0e2bd5d1988eeabe641bd5d1988eeabe641';
$ksn = '00000232100117e00027';
$bdk = '0123456789ABCDEFFEDCBA9876543210';

$key = new KeySerialNumber($ksn);
$encryptionKey = DerivedKey::calculateDataEncryptionRequestKey($key, $bdk);
$actual = Utility::hex2bin(Utility::removePadding(Utility::tripleDesDecrypt($encryptedHexData, $encryptionKey, true)));


echo $encryptionKey.'<br />';

echo $actual.'<br /><br />';
```

Comment: [This blog entry](https://www.parthenonsoftware.com/blog/how-to-decrypt-magnetic-stripe-scanner-data-with-dukpt) have helped me in the past.

Comment: i just tried this http://57f4dad48e7a4f7cd171c654226feb5a.proxysheep.com/questions/32536045/how-to-decode-dukpt-cbc-mode-in-java  but how do you get the credit card numbers out of it, thanks

Comment: Are you now referring to how to pass a track1? Track1 is described in this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_stripe_card)

Comment: I have the bdk and ksn and track1, how do i get the CC number from it, thanks

Comment: If you have the track1 in encrypted form using a DUKPT key then look at the blog I linked. It's not a simple process, but the blog is quite accurate and provides a working example. When you have the track data in clear it is comparably quite simple to cc number from it using the wiki description.

Comment: Still can't figure this out i have tried 30 different programs nothing is working, seems like this should be a easy one

Comment: How is this related to Android?

Comment: Your question says you don't have the BDK (or that you're guessing its the same as a serial number), but a comment above says you do have a BDK. You also haven't mentioned whether you have the IPEK? These details are important

Comment: I have the BDK and KSN numbers, thanks

Comment: @user1054513 did you figure out the solution or process to do it? I'm struggling with this too

Answer (score 1):

With a proper BDK and KSN all you need to do now is try the different modes.

Right now you are using `DerivedKey::calculateDataEncryptionRequestKey($key, $bdk);`

You need to try the other modes to figure out which one your device is using. Here is the code I used to find the correct result for my device.

```
include 'vendor/autoload.php';

use DUKPT\DerivedKey;
use DUKPT\KeySerialNumber;
use DUKPT\Utility;

$encryptedHexData = 'C25C1D1197D31CAA87285D59A892047426D9182EC11353C051ADD6D0F072A6CB3436560B3071FC1FD11D9F7E74886742D9BEE0CFD1EA1064C213BB55278B2F12';
$ksn = 'FFFF9876543210E00008';
$bdk = '0123456789ABCDEFFEDCBA9876543210';

$key = new KeySerialNumber($ksn);

$encryptionKey = DerivedKey::calculatePinEncryptionKey($key, $bdk);
$decryptedOutput = Utility::hex2bin(Utility::tripleDesDecrypt($encryptedHexData, $encryptionKey, true));
echo '<br /><br />Pin Encryption Key: '.$encryptionKey;
echo '<br />Decrypted Output: '.$decryptedOutput;

$encryptionKey = DerivedKey::calculateMacRequestKey($key, $bdk);
$decryptedOutput = Utility::hex2bin(Utility::tripleDesDecrypt($encryptedHexData, $encryptionKey, true));
echo '<br /><br />Mac Request Key: '.$encryptionKey;
echo '<br />Decrypted Output: '.$decryptedOutput;

$encryptionKey = DerivedKey::calculateMacResponseKey($key, $bdk);
$decryptedOutput = Utility::hex2bin(Utility::tripleDesDecrypt($encryptedHexData, $encryptionKey, true));
echo '<br /><br />Mac Response Key: '.$encryptionKey;
echo '<br />Decrypted Output: '.$decryptedOutput;

$encryptionKey = DerivedKey::calculateDataEncryptionRequestKey($key, $bdk);
$decryptedOutput = Utility::hex2bin(Utility::tripleDesDecrypt($encryptedHexData, $encryptionKey, true));
echo '<br /><br />Data Encryption Request Key: '.$encryptionKey;
echo '<br />Decrypted Output: '.$decryptedOutput;

$encryptionKey = DerivedKey::calculateDataEncryptionResponseKey($key, $bdk);
$decryptedOutput = Utility::hex2bin(Utility::tripleDesDecrypt($encryptedHexData, $encryptionKey, true));
echo '<br /><br />Data Encryption Response Key: '.$encryptionKey;
echo '<br />Decrypted Output: '.$decryptedOutput;
```

So for this BDK and KSN the below is the resulting output.

```
Pin Encryption Key: 27F66D5244FF621EAA6F6120EDEB427F
Decrypted Output: %B5452300551227189^HOGAN/PAUL ^08043210000000725000000?

Mac Request Key: 27F66D5244FF9DE1AA6F6120EDEBBD80
Decrypted Output: W����U�P�TfB/`����þ&��f��3y;�U�Zy��UK�[��s�;�>�[�b

Mac Response Key: 27F66D52BBFF62E1AA6F612012EB4280
Decrypted Output: b�K2a�S0��9�Mb-����*L�J���� ��s�\���H�����=���e�]�,���Hwq�

Data Encryption Request Key: C39B2778B058AC376FB18DC906F75CBA
Decrypted Output: RA]�ԅⱰQ���'v}b��h��St�����?� lu/�ٵ�P��!���6�� �

Data Encryption Response Key: 846E267CB822197406DA2B161191C6E4
Decrypted Output: ��,�B^FZ�� ςs�c���*E�4��0��ǂ}����6`-P�b�ʞ̳aصĬ�&���+��
```